# How can I add a twitter bootstrap span glyphicon into a button in html5?

Tags: django, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, icons

I am creating an app in django and I have the next problem: I want to add a glyphicon into the next button:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type=button name="name" onClick="location.href='/location/'" value='I am a button'>
```

Concretely, I want the glyphicon to be with the text 'I am a button'. How can I do it?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using input type button, you should try using button element
so something like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onClick="location.href='/location/'">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> I am a button 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the class as the icon class. For example `class="glyphicon glyphicon-off` for power button. Moreover remove the value of the button.